# How to use CMIS repo.query in a temp folder

Tags: python, alfresco, cmis

As part of an integration test, I create documents in a subfolder:

```
class CmisTestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """ Create a root test folder for the test. """
        logger.debug("Creating client")
        self.cmis_client = CmisClient(REPOSITORY_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        logger.debug("Getting default repo")
        self.repo = self.cmis_client.getDefaultRepository()
        logger.debug("Getting root folder")
        self.root_folder = self.repo.getObjectByPath(TEST_ROOT_PATH)
        logger.debug("Creating test folder")
        self.folder_name = ".".join(['cmislib', self.__class__.__name__, str(time.time())])
        self.test_folder = self.root_folder.createFolder(self.folder_name)

    def tearDown(self):
        """ Clean up after the test. """
        logger.debug("Deleting test folder")
        self.test_folder.deleteTree()
```

And in my tests I create documents and then test that I can query them using `repo.query`:

```
class SearchNoauth(SearchTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(SearchNoauth, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(SearchNoauth, self).tearDown()

    def test_noauth_empty(self):
        logger.debug("Calling test_noauth_empty")
        # Create a single document
        self.create_document_simple()
        # Retrieve all documents (No argument passed)
        response = self.client.profile_noauth()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        result_data = response.json()
        logger.debug("results: {0}".format(pformat(result_data, indent=4)))
        self.assertEqual(len(result_data), 1)
```

But as near as I can tell, my custom content created in the scope of the test is not found because the default repo does not search the test folder.

I'd expect an API:

- to allow searches against a folder (not just a repo) or
- to support a syntax for looking for objects in a specific folder

**How do I construct a CMIS query that finds matching custom documents in a folder?**

---

A bit more:

- `self.client.profile_noauth` is a call to `profile_noauth` method in a python client library
- that hits a Pyramid server
- that aggregates a number of services, including Alfresco,
- and eventually calls `repo.query` against an Alfresco default repository.

Much of this question is how to modify the facade service's CMIS query to look in a folder.

---

Later: I think [I may have an answer](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/return-last-object-folder-query-06292012-1509). The basic idea is to get the ID of the folder and use `in_folder()`:

```
>>> folder = repo.getObjectByPath('/Sites/test-site-1/documentLibrary')
>>> query = """
        select cmis:objectId, cmis:name
        from cmis:document
        where in_folder('%s')
        order by cmis:lastModificationDate desc
    """ % folder.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered the question in your post. If you want to query for documents in a specific folder you can use the in folder clause and that requires the ID of the folder you want to search.

Comment: I should add that if you want to query the folder and the folder's descendants you should use in_tree() instead of in_folder().